# SQL-Server 2008 How to compare Hour and minute only with current time

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, compare

I have field [end] on database datatype = DateTime
I want to compare [end] hour and minute only with current time Hour and minute only. I use C# for application

How do I do ?

Comment: Hi, can you share the code that you already have with us? Then we can help you to fix it

Answer (score 1):

This How I use with query on C#

```
"SELECT [end] FROM [table_name] WHERE CONVERT(char(5),[end], 108) = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm") + "'";
```

Comment: Converting a column is not sargable, so if you have an index on that column, it will be useless. Also is it your intention to ignore the date completely?

Comment: I just want to show the time where hour and minute is same. because the day is always same the difference is hour and minute only. is it can be a trouble someday ? @AaronBertrand

Comment: If you only care about hour and minute, why not use the `time` data type?

Comment: some times date is needed, but not in this case. This case I just want to show the time. is it could be a trouble some day ?

Answer (score 0):

To compare two datetime column type, you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE DATE_COMPARISION
(
MI_DATETIME DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO DATE_COMPARISION
VALUES (GETDATE())
```

**EDIT (thank you to  Aaron Bertrand)**

```
SELECT RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(hh,MI_DATETIME)),2)+
RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MI,MI_DATETIME)),2),
MI_DATETIME 
FROM DATE_COMPARISION
WHERE 
RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(hh,MI_DATETIME)),2)+
RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MI,MI_DATETIME)),2)
=
RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(hh,GETDATE())),2)
+RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MI,GETDATE())),2)
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Please read [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations). Also, this query will treat many times, e.g., 11:01 and 1:11, and 10:07 and 1:07, the same. Would be safer to multiply hours by 100 and add minutes (and this would also avoid messy conversions to strings). Still, the query is not sargable.

Comment: let me see, thank you so much, for the title can understand what you want to tell me, i will edit after read.

Comment: what is your advice about how make this script sargable ?.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, now that I understand the problem better, unless they added a computed column or split the date and time into separate columns.